# NSwag.MSBuild is timing out when added as target to a .csproj target

Tags: c#, msbuild, nswag

I'm teaching myself the basics of NSwag right now.  With the goal to standardize & automate my company's API Clients.  During this I found the NSwag.MSBuild which seemed perfect for my desires to build the API Client during our build pipelines.  Except when I use it, I get an infinitely long build that eventually times out.

Here's the code I created and am struggling with:
https://github.com/clbarrett/Basics

I've tried a few different things.  Running the nswag from the command line with `nswag run nswag.json /runtime:Net60` and the target disabled works fine.  I've successfully gone on to build a NuGet package and consume it inside a simple web app.

I can also get it to build if I set the noBuild property to true.  But then it stops picking up any changes to the controllers.

But the moment I add the NSwag target with the noBuild: false I get that timeout.  Doesn't matter if it is from Visual Studio or from a dotnet build command.

Here's my .csproj Target:

```
<Target Name="NSwag" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Exec Command="$(NSwagExe_Net60) run nswag.json" />
</Target>
```

Error Message I'm getting:

```
1>Executing file 'nswag.json' with variables ''...
1>System.InvalidOperationException: Process dotnet timed out.
1>   at NSwag.Commands.Generation.AspNetCore.Exe.RunAsync(String executable, IReadOnlyList`1 args, IConsoleHost console, Nullable`1 timeout) in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/Commands/Generation/AspNetCore/Exe.cs:line 66
1>   at NSwag.Commands.Generation.AspNetCore.ProjectMetadata.GetProjectMetadata(String file, String buildExtensionsDir, String framework, String configuration, String runtime, Boolean noBuild, String outputPath, IConsoleHost console) in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/Commands/Generation/AspNetCore/ProjectMetadata.cs:line 149
1>   at NSwag.Commands.Generation.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreToSwaggerCommand.RunAsync(CommandLineProcessor processor, IConsoleHost host) in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/Commands/Generation/AspNetCore/AspNetCoreToOpenApiCommand.cs:line 106
1>   at NSwag.Commands.NSwagDocumentBase.GenerateSwaggerDocumentAsync() in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/NSwagDocumentBase.cs:line 275
1>   at NSwag.Commands.NSwagDocument.ExecuteAsync() in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/NSwagDocument.cs:line 81
1>   at NSwag.Commands.Document.ExecuteDocumentCommand.ExecuteDocumentAsync(IConsoleHost host, String filePath) in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/Commands/Document/ExecuteDocumentCommand.cs:line 85
1>   at NSwag.Commands.Document.ExecuteDocumentCommand.RunAsync(CommandLineProcessor processor, IConsoleHost host) in /_/src/NSwag.Commands/Commands/Document/ExecuteDocumentCommand.cs:line 32
1>   at NConsole.CommandLineProcessor.ProcessSingleAsync(String[] args, Object input)
1>   at NConsole.CommandLineProcessor.ProcessAsync(String[] args, Object input)
```

nswag.json:

```
{
  "runtime": "Net60",
  "defaultVariables": null,
  "documentGenerator": {
    "aspNetCoreToOpenApi": {
      "project": "BasicAPI.csproj",
      "msBuildProjectExtensionsPath": null,
      "configuration": "appsettings.json",
      "runtime": "",
      "targetFramework": null,
      "noBuild": false,
      "msBuildOutputPath": null,
      "verbose": true,
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "requireParametersWithoutDefault": false,
      "apiGroupNames": null,
      "defaultPropertyNameHandling": "Default",
      "defaultReferenceTypeNullHandling": "Null",
      "defaultDictionaryValueReferenceTypeNullHandling": "NotNull",
      "defaultResponseReferenceTypeNullHandling": "NotNull",
      "generateOriginalParameterNames": true,
      "defaultEnumHandling": "Integer",
      "flattenInheritanceHierarchy": false,
      "generateKnownTypes": true,
      "generateEnumMappingDescription": false,
      "generateXmlObjects": false,
      "generateAbstractProperties": false,
      "generateAbstractSchemas": true,
      "ignoreObsoleteProperties": false,
      "allowReferencesWithProperties": false,
      "useXmlDocumentation": true,
      "resolveExternalXmlDocumentation": true,
      "excludedTypeNames": [],
      "serviceHost": null,
      "serviceBasePath": null,
      "serviceSchemes": [],
      "infoTitle": "My Title",
      "infoDescription": null,
      "infoVersion": "1.0.0",
      "documentTemplate": null,
      "documentProcessorTypes": [],
      "operationProcessorTypes": [],
      "typeNameGeneratorType": null,
      "schemaNameGeneratorType": null,
      "contractResolverType": null,
      "serializerSettingsType": null,
      "useDocumentProvider": true,
      "documentName": "v1",
      "aspNetCoreEnvironment": null,
      "createWebHostBuilderMethod": null,
      "startupType": null,
      "allowNullableBodyParameters": true,
      "useHttpAttributeNameAsOperationId": false,
      "output": null,
      "outputType": "Swagger2",
      "newLineBehavior": "Auto",
      "assemblyPaths": [],
      "assemblyConfig": null,
      "referencePaths": [],
      "useNuGetCache": false
    }
  },
  "codeGenerators": {
    "openApiToCSharpClient": {
      "clientBaseClass": null,
      "configurationClass": null,
      "generateClientClasses": true,
      "generateClientInterfaces": false,
      "clientBaseInterface": null,
      "injectHttpClient": true,
      "disposeHttpClient": true,
      "protectedMethods": [],
      "generateExceptionClasses": true,
      "exceptionClass": "ApiException",
      "wrapDtoExceptions": true,
      "useHttpClientCreationMethod": false,
      "httpClientType": "System.Net.Http.HttpClient",
      "useHttpRequestMessageCreationMethod": false,
      "useBaseUrl": true,
      "generateBaseUrlProperty": true,
      "generateSyncMethods": false,
      "generatePrepareRequestAndProcessResponseAsAsyncMethods": false,
      "exposeJsonSerializerSettings": false,
      "clientClassAccessModifier": "public",
      "typeAccessModifier": "public",
      "generateContractsOutput": false,
      "contractsNamespace": null,
      "contractsOutputFilePath": null,
      "parameterDateTimeFormat": "s",
      "parameterDateFormat": "yyyy-MM-dd",
      "generateUpdateJsonSerializerSettingsMethod": true,
      "useRequestAndResponseSerializationSettings": false,
      "serializeTypeInformation": false,
      "queryNullValue": "",
      "className": "{controller}Client",
      "operationGenerationMode": "MultipleClientsFromOperationId",
      "additionalNamespaceUsages": [],
      "additionalContractNamespaceUsages": [],
      "generateOptionalParameters": false,
      "generateJsonMethods": false,
      "enforceFlagEnums": false,
      "parameterArrayType": "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable",
      "parameterDictionaryType": "System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary",
      "responseArrayType": "System.Collections.Generic.ICollection",
      "responseDictionaryType": "System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary",
      "wrapResponses": false,
      "wrapResponseMethods": [],
      "generateResponseClasses": true,
      "responseClass": "SwaggerResponse",
      "namespace": "BasicAPIClient",
      "requiredPropertiesMustBeDefined": true,
      "dateType": "System.DateTimeOffset",
      "jsonConverters": null,
      "anyType": "object",
      "dateTimeType": "System.DateTimeOffset",
      "timeType": "System.TimeSpan",
      "timeSpanType": "System.TimeSpan",
      "arrayType": "System.Collections.Generic.ICollection",
      "arrayInstanceType": "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection",
      "dictionaryType": "System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary",
      "dictionaryInstanceType": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary",
      "arrayBaseType": "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection",
      "dictionaryBaseType": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary",
      "classStyle": "Poco",
      "jsonLibrary": "NewtonsoftJson",
      "generateDefaultValues": true,
      "generateDataAnnotations": true,
      "excludedTypeNames": [],
      "excludedParameterNames": [],
      "handleReferences": false,
      "generateImmutableArrayProperties": false,
      "generateImmutableDictionaryProperties": false,
      "jsonSerializerSettingsTransformationMethod": null,
      "inlineNamedArrays": false,
      "inlineNamedDictionaries": false,
      "inlineNamedTuples": true,
      "inlineNamedAny": false,
      "generateDtoTypes": true,
      "generateOptionalPropertiesAsNullable": false,
      "generateNullableReferenceTypes": false,
      "templateDirectory": null,
      "typeNameGeneratorType": null,
      "propertyNameGeneratorType": null,
      "enumNameGeneratorType": null,
      "serviceHost": null,
      "serviceSchemes": null,
      "output": "../BasicAPIClient/BasicAPIClient.cs",
      "newLineBehavior": "Auto"
    }
  }
}
```